# qTip 2 - Mousedown to reveal tooltip? Mouseup to hide?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having real issues trying to find a way to reveal a tooltip with .mousedown and hide it again with .mouseup.

qTip looks like the neatest library but after an hour's googling and playing in jsfiddle I can't get anywhere closer than their default examples.

The documentation doesn't show mousedown as event for revealing - can anyone help point me in the right direction?

I've made a default very simple fiddle as a starting point if anyone can help me from there:

http://jsfiddle.net/craga89/fDavN/

```
$('.selector').qtip({
content: {
    text: 'My content'
}
});
```

The library is: http://qtip2.com/options

Edit... it doesn't have to be qTip if that helps - just a solid jquery tooltip library.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using "Tooltipster"

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 // first on page load, initiate the Tooltipster plugin
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
    trigger: custom,
    });

// reveal when mousedown is called
 $(window).mousedown(function() {
  $('#example').tooltipster('show');
});
 // hide when mouseup is called
 $(window).mouseup(function() {
  $('#example').tooltipster('hide');
 });

});
```